# Ubuntu booting error, stopped at loading ubuntu image

Tags: boot

I have installed ubuntu latest version and i've been using the same installation for the two last months. But suddenly two days back looks like it had crashed and after restarting it's not booting correctly. It gets stuck at the ubuntu loading screen. (the logo)

I am getting the below error for almost 5 min and then got stuck:

```
  READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

I have taken backup using an USB stick.

Could you please help me resolving the error above? I had no luck figuring it out myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the hard drive. Check your ATA cables(hard drive cables). [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133946/are-these-sata-errors-dangerous) is somewhat related to yours'. Give it a try, it may solve your problem.