# getting issue when booting system in Ubuntu 14 in laptop

Tags: boot, grub2, laptop

I am getting these kind of errors when booting system:

```
READ FPDMA QUEUED (DRDY ERR) 
READ DMA EXT
```

What I need to do for this? Is this HDD issue? I should replace it with new HDD?

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/133946/are-these-sata-errors-dangerous and probably http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2272486

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar question here that was already solved. Take a look if the same solution works with your issue too. Click this link: [Are these sata errors dangerous?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133946/are-these-sata-errors-dangerous)