# Cannot install Ubuntu 16.04 from USB

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I have repeated the whole process three times,trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 from my USB.But when I try to restart the computer I got

```
[  5.744249] ata16.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  5.744257] ata16.00: irq_stat 0x400000001
[  5.744265] ata16.00: cmd a0/01:00:00:00:00:01
```

and so on
I have tried to Google it. It seems that I have hardware incompatibility. Yes or no?
What is really crazy is that I can choose that option try Ubuntu without installing it and appears Ubuntu with Unity icons.My hardware spec

```
Intel Core i7 DX580G
Seagate Desktop HDD
Marvel Sata Controler
```

What should I try?

Comment: does a live USB or DVD boot up?

Comment: @Jeroen No,when I restart system appears: No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

Comment: @Jeroen Should I go for try Ubuntu without installing it?

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/133946/are-these-sata-errors-dangerous,

Comment: Are you accessing the BIOS to change the boot order so your machine will boot from the USB device? And what kind of machine are you trying to install Ubuntu on it makes a world of difference. Please provide the specs for your machine

Comment: @RobGoss Will try to change boot order now.

Comment: @RobGoss Please,take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you verify the checksum of the image. On the Ubuntu download page you will find a .md5 or .sha256 file to download. here is the ubuntu docs
[How to MD5 sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)